# Looking for method to organize TypeScript Imports while refactoring

Tags: visual-studio-code

When code refactoring, i would like to automatically find and/or remove unnecessarily imports and to automatically import the missing one (at one time and not one by one) on existing document.

I know that the editor will automatically import while typing. i would like to do that after refactoring (copy paste of many sections on existing document).

Answer (score 0):

v1.23 visual studio code release introduced this feature. 
click [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_run-code-actions-on-save) for Information on how to enable this

Alternatively, you can manually run this action by pressing Shift+Alt+O.